# problem in using last function in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, window

I want to fill `null` values over my window with last value of every window. But in some cases I think `last` functions doesn't work.
Here is my data:

```
l = [
     ('100', '2012-01-02', None),
     ('110', '2012-01-02', None),
     ('100', '2012-01-03', 26),
     ('110', '2012-01-03', 251),
     ('100', '2012-01-04', 24),
     ('110', '2012-01-04', 242),
     ('100', '2012-01-05', 26),
     ('110', '2012-01-05', 254),
     ('100', '2012-01-06', 0),
     ('110', '2012-01-06', 254),
     ('100', '2012-01-07', 25),
     ('110', '2012-01-07', 256),
     ('100', '2012-01-08', 28),
     ('110', '2012-01-08', 0),
     ('100', '2012-01-09', 22),
     ('110', '2012-01-09', 289),
     ('100', '2012-01-10', 29),
     ('110', '2012-01-10', 276),
     ('100', '2012-01-11', 21),
     ('110', '2012-01-11', 259),
     ('100', '2012-01-12', 32),
     ('110', '2012-01-12', 280),
     ('100', '2012-01-13', 39),
     ('110', '2012-01-13', 290)
    ]
df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['number', 'date', 'count'])
```

This is my Expected output:

```
+------+----------+-----+
|number|      date|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|   100|2012-01-02|   39|
|   100|2012-01-03|   26|
|   100|2012-01-04|   24|
|   100|2012-01-05|   26|
|   100|2012-01-06|    0|
|   100|2012-01-07|   25|
|   100|2012-01-08|   28|
|   100|2012-01-09|   22|
|   100|2012-01-10|   29|
|   100|2012-01-11|   21|
|   100|2012-01-12|   32|
|   100|2012-01-13|   39|
|   110|2012-01-02|  290|
|   110|2012-01-03|  251|
|   110|2012-01-04|  242|
|   110|2012-01-05|  254|
|   110|2012-01-06|  254|
|   110|2012-01-07|  256|
|   110|2012-01-08|    0|
|   110|2012-01-09|  289|
+------+----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

When I using last function My
`null` values doesn't fill as you see:

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('number').orderBy(df['date'])
df.withColumn('count', F.when(df['count'].isNull(), F.last(df['count']).over(my_window)).otherwise(df['count'])).show()

+------+----------+-----+
|number|      date|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|   110|2012-01-02| null|
|   110|2012-01-03|  251|
|   110|2012-01-04|  242|
|   110|2012-01-05|  254|
|   110|2012-01-06|  254|
|   110|2012-01-07|  256|
|   110|2012-01-08|    0|
|   110|2012-01-09|  289|
|   110|2012-01-10|  276|
|   110|2012-01-11|  259|
|   110|2012-01-12|  280|
|   110|2012-01-13|  290|
|   100|2012-01-02| null|
|   100|2012-01-03|   26|
|   100|2012-01-04|   24|
|   100|2012-01-05|   26|
|   100|2012-01-06|    0|
|   100|2012-01-07|   25|
|   100|2012-01-08|   28|
|   100|2012-01-09|   22|
+------+----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

But when I changed my order by to desc and use `first` function it does work:

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('number').orderBy(df['date'].desc())
df.withColumn('count', F.when(df['count'].isNull(), F.first(df['count']).over(my_window)).otherwise(df['count'])).show()

+------+----------+-----+
|number|      date|count|
+------+----------+-----+
|   110|2012-01-13|  290|
|   110|2012-01-12|  280|
|   110|2012-01-11|  259|
|   110|2012-01-10|  276|
|   110|2012-01-09|  289|
|   110|2012-01-08|    0|
|   110|2012-01-07|  256|
|   110|2012-01-06|  254|
|   110|2012-01-05|  254|
|   110|2012-01-04|  242|
|   110|2012-01-03|  251|
|   110|2012-01-02|  290|
|   100|2012-01-13|   39|
|   100|2012-01-12|   32|
|   100|2012-01-11|   21|
|   100|2012-01-10|   29|
|   100|2012-01-09|   22|
|   100|2012-01-08|   28|
|   100|2012-01-07|   25|
|   100|2012-01-06|    0|
+------+----------+-----+
only showing top 20 rows
```

can anyone help me with this problem??

Comment: @484 I've changed my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your window to this.

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('number').orderBy(df['date']).rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)
```

Your window imposes the rows between the first row to the current and in this case, the last is the same as the current.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is long overdue, but for people trying to understand why this happens
(I'm no expert but I'll just relay what I've been told)

I did have the same problem and I asked around at work and after digging it up a little bit I've been told that when we use "orderBy" in the window Spark will create a partition to order it and when used with Last or Max/Min it won't work. If your data is already ordered and you use

```
my_window = Window.partitionBy('number')
```

Without the orderBy, it will work. It will catch the last thing it sees on the window, so may you have an ordered dataset (mine was because I've previously used another window function with orderBy so it sorted the dataset) it will work.

However, whenever you have to use orderBy in a window do not use Last unless you specify the rolls between, but watch out for performance! I did try the given solution of using

> `rowsBetween(Window.currentRow, Window.unboundedFollowing)`

and it made my processing time go from 30s to 13m, and this happened because for a yet unknown reason spark put all the data in the same partition. If this is not an issue for you, it is a great solution. For me, I ended up using "reverse first" just like you did at the end because I thought it was more understandable and less prone to error if someone in the future were to maintain my code (me included lol I do forget what I myself have coded)